# Law of the unconscious statistician, is there a condition on g?

Tags: probability, expected-value

What are the criteria that $g(X)$ needs to satistify before we can write $E(g(X))=\int_{x \in \Omega}g(x)f_X(x)dx$??

Comment: In order to consider $\mathbb E[g(X)]$ $g(X)$ must be a random variable, which means that the function $g$ must be measurable.